# The WSDL cannot be generated from the web service due to error

Tags: eclipse, oracle, wsdl, weblogic

I'm working with the Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse. Therefore I tried to create a little Oracle Web Service project. In there there's nothing else than the auto-generated method hello(). However everytime I try to create a WSDL File (right click etc.) I get this error:

```
The WSDL cannot be generated from the web service due to error
```

Errorlog:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                at oracle.eclipse.tools.webservices.ant.WlsAntScript.execute(WlsAntScript.java:288)
                at oracle.eclipse.tools.webservices.ui.actions.GenerateWsdlFromJwscAntAction$1.run(GenerateWsdlFromJwscAntAction.java:217)
                at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: oracle.eclipse.tools.webservices.ant.GeneratedAntScriptFailedException: Generated ant script failed:
C:\Users\steinkar\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\oracle.eclipse.tools.webservices\ant\build.xml 
Log file:
C:\Users\steinkar\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\oracle.eclipse.tools.webservices\ant\build_log.txt
Log contents:
Buildfile: C:\Users\steinkar\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\oracle.eclipse.tools.webservices\ant\build.xml
Trying to override old definition of datatype wsgen

fork_build:

BUILD FAILED
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Develop\Oracle\Middleware\jdk160_29\bin\java" (in directory "C:\Users\steinkar\eclipse\workspace\tc_togo"): CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect
                at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
                at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:832)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:447)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:461)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.fork(Java.java:784)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:211)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:132)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:105)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
                at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
                at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:665)
                at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:498)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
                at org.eclipse.ant.core.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:378)
                at oracle.eclipse.tools.webservices.ant.WlsAntScript.runAnt(WlsAntScript.java:128)
                at oracle.eclipse.tools.webservices.ant.WlsAntScript.execute(WlsAntScript.java:283)
                at oracle.eclipse.tools.webservices.ui.actions.GenerateWsdlFromJwscAntAction$1.run(GenerateWsdlFromJwscAntAction.java:217)
                at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect
                at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
                at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:81)
                at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
                at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
                ... 37 more

Total time: 0 seconds


                at oracle.eclipse.tools.webservices.ant.WlsAntScript.runAnt(WlsAntScript.java:130)
                at oracle.eclipse.tools.webservices.ant.WlsAntScript.execute(WlsAntScript.java:283)
                ... 2 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: C:\Users\steinkar\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\oracle.eclipse.tools.webservices\ant\build.xml:10: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Develop\Oracle\Middleware\jdk160_29\bin\java" (in directory "C:\Users\steinkar\eclipse\workspace\tc_togo"): CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect
                at org.eclipse.ant.core.AntRunner.handleInvocationTargetException(AntRunner.java:452)
                at org.eclipse.ant.core.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:384)
                at oracle.eclipse.tools.webservices.ant.WlsAntScript.runAnt(WlsAntScript.java:128)
                ... 3 more
Caused by: C:\Users\steinkar\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\oracle.eclipse.tools.webservices\ant\build.xml:10: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Develop\Oracle\Middleware\jdk160_29\bin\java" (in directory "C:\Users\steinkar\eclipse\workspace\tc_togo"): CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect
                at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.fork(Java.java:791)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:211)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:132)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:105)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
                at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
                at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:665)
                at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:498)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
                at org.eclipse.ant.core.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:378)
                ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Develop\Oracle\Middleware\jdk160_29\bin\java" (in directory "C:\Users\steinkar\eclipse\workspace\tc_togo"): CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect
                at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
                at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:832)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:447)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:461)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.fork(Java.java:784)
                ... 28 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect
                at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
                at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:81)
                at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
                at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
                ... 37 more
```

I've tried deleting the project, reinstalling the Oracle thing but it still isn't working although the webservice itself is running. Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some things you should make sure.
First: Don't install the Oracle Software to another location than the default one. For some reason the software doesn't work right then.
Second: Don't create your workspace at a long directory.

If you fixed both it should work.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'll try this. Is it really possible that the non-standard installation directory could cause that?

Comment: unfortunatelly it is possible. had the same problem weeks ago.